# How to use the FormlyConfig for custom type with angular 4

Tags: angular-formly

I am using formly form (ngx-formly-form )in angular 4 , i want to create the custom type for toggle functionality like "Yes" or "No" buttons.
Can any one share the example of how to use FormlyConfig in angular 4.
I found some example but which is angular js specific.

Answer (score 0):

well, I think it can be implemented easily if you follow the doc https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-field which shows you how to create a custom field type.

if you're looking for a working example see https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-custom-template-3yvkcd